# Why component state automatically changed (reactjs)?

Tags: reactjs

When I first login, the logout link appear and the initial state of open variable is true, but my initial state of the open variable should be false which I suppose do not show this link.

I try to add log out whether toggleOpen() method automatically called on render, but found it has not been called.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
class UserMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
         this.toggleOpen = this.toggleOpen.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            open:false
        }
    }
    logout(){
        Meteor.logout();
    }
    toggleOpen() {
        this.setState({open:!this.state.open});
    }
    renderLoggedIn(){
        const user = this.props.user;
        return (
             <div className='user-menu vertical'>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.toggleOpen}>{user.username}<span className={`icon-arrow-${this.state.open?"up":"down"}`}></span></a>
                {this.state.open &&  <a href="#" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a>}
            </div>
        );
    }
    renderLoggedOut(){
        return (
            <div className='user-menu'>
                <Link to='/signin'>Sign In</Link>
                <Link to='/join'>Join</Link>
            </div>
        );  
    }
    render() {
        const user = this.props.user;
        return user? this.renderLoggedIn():this.renderLoggedOut();
    }
}

export default UserMenu;
```

I expected the logout link should not appear before I click the toggleOpen().

Comment: Strange. Try adding console.log(this.state.open) in render. What do you get?

Comment: Your code is working fine- https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-cnd21?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

Does the open state changes to false when clicking the `<a />`? 
One fix could be use string for open state variable, like `{open: 'opened'}` or `{open:'closed'}` and do a string comparision, like `this.state.open === 'opened'`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found it. The open state has not been reset(still true) when click logout, so reset back to false when logout is clicked is the answer.

```
logout(){
    Meteor.logout();
    this.setState({open:false});
}
```